# Where to find file that is written by FileOutputStream?

Tags: android, fileoutputstream

I am trying to use `FileOutputStream` to create a text file that will write data into it (saving to internal storage). However, it doesn't even generates the text file. I tried finding the text file using DDMS every single time I test run my codes but it's not there. I can't find the package name folder in the /data/data directory. I am clueless why it is not working as Eclipse didn't complain about any errors with my code too.

Code:

```
public void saveGroup(String grpName)
{
    try
    {
        FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("data.txt", MODE_PRIVATE);
        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fos);

        Team newTeam = new Team(grpName, memberList);
        String s = newTeam.name + "|" + newTeam.getMembers();

        osw.write(s);
        osw.flush();
        osw.close();

        invalidCharacterToast("Saved");
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Team is a class that I have created myself.

Comment: Added appropriate permissions?

Comment: are you using an emulator or an actual device?

Comment: @pdriegen i'm using an emulator

Answer (score 2):

As per the [Android Documentation on openFileOutput](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileOutput%28java.lang.String,%20int%29), it creates a private file for writing.
If you are using the emulator, you will see the file in /data/data/< packagename >/files folder. On the other hand if you're using a physical, non-rooted device, this area is inaccessible via DDMS.

Have you tried reading the file after writing it via openFileInput?